# reshape numpy arrays in iterator

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, reshape

Say I have a list of numpy arrays. How can I reshape the arrays in the list?
Here is an example, where I want to ensure all my arrays have two dimensions:

```
In [0]: import numpy as np
   ...: arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3]) # Shape is (3,) --> Will need reshaping
   ...: arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]]) # Shape is (1, 3) --> Shape ok
   ...: list_of_arrays = [arr1, arr2]
   ...: for i, arr in enumerate(list_of_arrays):
   ...:     print("\narray number {}, initial shape: {}".format(i, arr.shape))
   ...:     if len(arr.shape)==1:
   ...:         print("needs reshaping")
   ...:         arr = np.reshape(arr, (1, arr.shape[0]))
   ...:         print("new shape: {}".format(arr.shape))
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print("shape ok")
```

This prints out, as expected:

```
array number 0, initial shape: (3,)
needs reshaping
new shape: (1, 3)

array number 1, initial shape: (1, 3)
shape ok
```

However, the result is cast to `arr`, not the array I actually want to modify, `arr1`:

```
In [1]: arr1.shape
Out[1]: (3,)
```

How do I cast the result to `arr1`?

Note that I need the elements of my list to be modified, not the list itself. In other words, I want to be able to modify `arr1` directly: it will be passed as an argument as `arr1` and not as `list_of_arrays[0]`.

Comment: The result is cast to `arr`, not to the array you actually want to reshape.

Comment: Exactly. So how do I cast to the array I actually want to reshape? I'll change my text to reflect this comment.

Comment: `list_of_arrays = list(map(np.atleast_2d, list_of_arrays))` is an option :) e.g. explicitly mapping the result. Of course, in case of a different desired dimension, you can also use a lambda function instead of np.atleast_2d to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I need the elements of my list to be modified, not the list itself. In other words, I want to be able to modify `arr1` directly: it will be passed as an argument as `arr1` and not as `list_of_arrays[0]`. Edited question to make that clearer.

Comment: If the argument is the temporary `arr` anyway, without wanting to cast it back, why not just pass it through the function you want to execute with it in the for loop?

Comment: The argument that will be passed is `arr1`, not the temporary `arr`. But I think I'll avoid the whole issue by using a decorator.

Comment: `np.vstack` uses `[atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup]`.  This makes a new list but the arrays are views if possible.  To change a list in-place use `alist[i] = np.reshape(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic array iteration problem.

```
for i in alist:
   i = ...
```

reassigns `i` inside the loop, and thus does not affect the source list.  You have to either mutate `i` itself, or index the list.

```
In [552]: arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3]) # Shape is (3,) --> Will need reshaping
     ...: arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]]) # Shape is (1, 3) --> Shape ok
     ...: list_of_arrays = [arr1, arr2]
     ...: for i, arr in enumerate(list_of_arrays):
     ...:    if len(arr.shape)==1:
     ...:        list_of_arrays[i] = np.reshape(arr, (1, arr.shape[0])) 
In [553]: list_of_arrays
Out[553]: [array([[1, 2, 3]]), array([[1, 2, 3]])]
```

`reshape` creates a new view of an array, but the shape can be modified in-place:

```
 In [554]: arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3]) # Shape is (3,) --> Will need reshaping
     ...: arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]]) # Shape is (1, 3) --> Shape ok
     ...: list_of_arrays = [arr1, arr2]
     ...: for arr in list_of_arrays:
     ...:    if len(arr.shape)==1:
     ...:        arr.shape = (1, arr.shape[0])
```

But often it is easier, and maybe even faster, to create a new list.  For example `np.vstack` uses

```
alist = [np.atleast_2d(arr) for arr in list_of_arrays]
```

to ensure that all the input arrays are 2d.  List comprehensions like this are widely used in Python. `list(map(np.atleast_2d, list_arrays))` is equivalent, but to my thinking not quite as readable.

Comment: "`reshape` creates a new view of an array, but the shape can be modified in-place"==>This is *exactly* what I was looking for.